# fakewaffle responsive tab screen issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I'm using fakewaffle responsive tab plugin but there is something that I didn't understand is I want to make responsive on 480px not 768px but I couldn't how can I did it ?

HTML

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs responsive" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#messages">Messages</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content responsive">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">...content...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">...content...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">...content...</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).tab('show')
});

(function ($) {
    fakewaffle.responsiveTabs(['xs', 'sm']);
})(jQuery);
```

[click to see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eQJME/)

Comment: see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rQZym/18/. Is this you need?

Comment: no it must be just 480px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove this `sm`. sm take 768 screen

```js
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).tab('show')
});

(function ($) {
   var windowSize = $(window).width();
   if(windowSize < 480){
     fakewaffle.responsiveTabs(['xs']);
   }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: but it just work on 768px I want to make it on 480px thanks

Comment: on 768 screen the tab must be behave like tab, and 767 and below it will work like accordian , thats what you need right ?

Comment: no..my fakewaffle js code must work on 480px :) I mean I want my links be tab on 480px not 768px

Comment: if you have commented this line `(function ($) {
    fakewaffle.responsiveTabs(['xs']);
})(jQuery);` it will work tab modal 768 and 480

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127778/discussion-between-jishnu-v-s-and-recruit-man).